# Spring data elasticsearch subaggregation not giving parent child results in aggregation results

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data

I am using spring data elastisearch and constructed a query with subaggregation. When I debug and copy the value of the created query and execute from sense plugin/postman I am getting correct result with subaggregation on 2 fields i.e. one field inside other, however the response returned by the program does not contain one field inside other but contains only the parent level field in the aggregation results.

Can you tell me what I might be doing wrong. Please see below for the more information about this

Document skeleton is like

```
{
    ...
    "gender":"Men",
    "category":"Shirts",
    .....
} ,
{
    ...
    "gender":"Men",
    "category":"Pants",
    .....
},
{
    ...
    "gender":"Women",
    "category":"Pants",
    .....
}
```

etc.

Expected output in aggregation is like

```
...

"aggregations": {
      "gender": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "Men",
               "doc_count": 4,
               "category": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "shirts",
                        "doc_count": 2
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "pants",
                        "doc_count": 2
                     }
                     ]
                }
            },
            {
               "key": "Women",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "category": {              
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "pants",
                        "doc_count": 2
                     }
                     ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }

 }
 ....
```

Java Code Code to add subaggregation of type term aggregation.

```
        for (Object aggregationField : request.getAggregationFields()) {
            TermsBuilder termBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms(aggregationField.toString())
                    .field(aggregationField.toString()).size(0);
            if(aggregationField.toString().equals("gender"))
            {
                TermsBuilder platformBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms("category").field("category").size(0);
                termBuilder.subAggregation(platformBuilder);
            }               
            nativeSearchQueryBuilder.addAggregation(termBuilder);
        }
```

Comment: You should probably paste your Java code, it'll be easier to help you out.

Comment: @Val Thanks, I have edited the question and added bit more information. Please let me know if I am able to explain myself correctly